How to multiply $n$ terms with a symmetrical geometric construction?
Given two segments of length $a$ and $b$ and a segment of length $1$, we can construct a segment of length $ab$ through the following diagram based on the power of point property. This is just one of many geometric diagrams which allow us to make such a construction.

What about for multiplying three lengths? We could use the same diagram twice, of course, but that would create an asymmetric mess. Multiplication is a commutative operation, so a proper diagram should take $a, b, c$ into symmetric roles. For this, we can use the following alternative diagram, in which $r$ is the inradius of a triangle with side lengths $a+b$, $b+c$ and $c+a$, thus, have length $r = \sqrt{\dfrac{abc}{a+b+c}}$.

This is not quite the product we want, but we can easily square it and multiply it by $a+b+c$ (which, mind you, is symmetric and easy to construct). For four or more lengths this diagram stops working. In fact, if we build a tangencial quadrilateral with side lengths $a+b$, $b+c$, $c+d$ and $d+a$, its inradius is $\sqrt{\dfrac{abc+bcd+cda+dab}{a+b+c+d}}$ as opposite to $\sqrt{\dfrac{abcd}{a+b+c+d}}$, as one could have hoped for.
Brahmagupta's formula features a quadruple product, stating a cyclic quadrilateral of side lengths $x, y, z, w$ have area $\dfrac14\sqrt{(s-x)(s-y)(s-z)(s-w)}$ where $s:=\dfrac{x+y+z+w}2$. This is promising, as we can take the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
s &= \dfrac{x+y+z+w}2\\
a &= s-x\\
b &= s-y\\
c &= s-z\\
d &= s-w
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
s &= \dfrac{a+b+c+d}2\\
x &= s-a\\
y &= s-b\\
z &= s-c\\
w &= s-d
\end{cases}$$
and build a cyclic quadrilateral with side lengths $x, y, z, w$, so that its area is $\dfrac14\sqrt{abcd}$. It is easy to see these values always satisfy the triangular inequality, therefore, in fact, form a quadrilateral, and it is true that if you can build a quadrilateral then you can also build a cyclic one with the same side lengths. Again, this method doesn't seem trivial to generalize as the formula for the area of a cyclic pentagon on its side lengths is very ugly.
How can we construct the value of $abcde$ using a symmetric geometric construction in the positive measures of $a, b, c, d, e$? And, more generally, what about for an arbitrary amount of lengths? Can any of the methods above be extended somehow?

To use the diagram you presented twice is quite Straightforward approach and not messy at all.

What is the precise definition of this geometrical construction you have in mind ? Are you adhering to the classical/strict straightedge + compass construction ? In that case, the construction in the case $n=4$ does not seem trivial since it requires the circumcircle first.
It seems that you want to recover $a_1a_2\dots a_n$ as some very fundamental quantity of a geometric object $G(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ that is invariant under permutation. But that is an extremely vague definition.

@dezdichado you are correct on your interpretation of the statement. I'm not necessarily interested in straightedge + compass constructions, I'm only looking for some symmetric fundamental geometric representation of a product. You think the question as stated is too vague to be answered? Do you have any suggestions on how to make it more specific?
